# why does wavelength of laser increase by temperature?

Tags: optics, waves

why does wavelength of laser increase by temperature?

I used a laser with a wavelength of 635nm.

The wavelength of the laser was 637nm at 293K.

Comment: Maybe because your laser cavity is expanding?

Answer (score 7):

Diode lasers are made of semiconductors. The bandgap of a semiconductor changes with temperature. In your case, when heated the band gap was smaller and the energy of the emitted photons was smaller so the wavelength was larger.

As you run the laser and it heats up from the current, you may see the wavelength change. Depending on the structure of the laser it may mode hop and jump to another wavelength.

Many laser diode controllers will also have a temperature sensor and thermoelectric device with a feedback loop to keep the temperature constant, or to tune the diode laser to a specific wavelength.

If you look on the data sheet for diode lasers they will usually have some wavelength vs temperature information.